# How do I end a game once a condition has been met?

Tags: swift, xcode11

I'm making a battleship game on Xcode 11 using Storyboards, and I've pretty much done everything except a Game Over screen and stop registering the guesses once the counter reaches 0. This is also my first time making a game on my own. Here's one of the IBActions I made for the buttons:

```
 @IBAction func square1Button(_ sender: Any) {
        if randomNum == 1 {
            square1.image = UIImage(named: "ShipPatrolHull")
        } else {
            guesses -= 1
            Turns.text = String(guesses)
            if guesses == 0 {

            }
        }
    }
```

The if statement in the else statement is empty because I don't know what to add there to make the variable guesses stop going down and to make a Game Over screen to show. I've also added a Storyboard called GameOver and is linked back to the main storyboard.

Comment: You could look into how to create (and present) a second View Controller. Your question doesn't give a lot of detail, maybe you are using Storyboards? You'll need to add a "game over" view controller to the storyboard, then segue to that. Hopefully that's enough of a clue to get moving forward.

Comment: oh sorry, I am using Storyboards, and thank you for telling me about making another storyboard, i didn't think about that, but how would I connect it in the viewController though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display a Game Over UIAlertController and then have the game reset when they select "Play Again." However, you mention that you already have another Storyboard for a separate Game Over screen. All you need to do is present that Game Over view controller. Make sure to set the storyboard identifier for the view controller you are trying to present so you can access it in code. See below for guidance,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameOverView")
```

From here you can easily present it.

```
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Lastly, to make the guesses stop going down, reorganize your if-statements in order to only subtract one from the guesses if the guesses value is not equal to zero, otherwise... game over.

```
if guesses != 0 {
    Turns.text = String(guesses)
    guesses -= 1
} else {
    //Game over, reset, etc.
}
```

Comment: I tried to declare the variables controller and storyboard like you did, but got the error "Cannot override with a stored property 'storyboard'" on both of them, and when I thought to change the names of the variables, the former controller var got the error "Cannot use instance member 'game' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm... try my updated answer for the storyboard declaration.

Comment: ok, the storyboard declaration is fixed, it just had to be in a function, so there are no errors, except for when it reaches 0 guesses, now the only error is "Thread 1: Exception: "Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x60000142e280>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'GameOverView'" I tried messing around with the Storydboard identifiers but I got the same error, just the name was different. Sorry to keep bothering you with this

Comment: Make sure you're setting the identifier to that string for the view controller itself (not sure if you have it embedded in a navigation controller or not, if so, its easy to accidentally select the navigation controller instead), and make sure to check the box that says something like "Use Storyboard Identifier" just under it.